# How to set c++ application name and icon on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I have a C++ application with Qt UI that needs to run on both Windows and Mac. I use Jamplus to compile it.
In QtDesigner I set the application name (for example "My Application") and icon, but on Mac the name that I set is only displayed in window header, and in the taskbar it shows filename instead (for example myapplication.debug) and default terminal icon. On Windows, title and icon are shown correctly both in window header and taskbar.
I googled for it, but I have discovered only that I can change it in XCode project settings, but I don't use it and I need solution that does not depend on it.
What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

To set an icon on a Mac you add `ICON = /path/to/your/icon.icns` into your `.pro` file, for the application name change the `TARGET` in your `.pro` file to what you want your application file name to be.

Comment: Thanks, but .pro is a config file that is used by XCode, isn't it? I need a solution without XCode.

Comment: The `.pro` file is the qmake project file typically used to build Qt applications.

Comment: Thanks. I also do not use QMake. Is there any other way?

Comment: I've tried via QCoreApplication::setApplicationName(), but it also works only on WIndows.

Answer (score 0):

You should either set `ICON = icon.icns` variable in `.pro` project file, or set icon directly in `Info.plist` file:

> 1. Create an `Info.plist` file for your application (using the `PropertyListEditor`, found in `Developer/Applications`).
> 2. Associate your `.icns` record with the `CFBundleIconFile` record in the `Info.plist` file (again, using the `PropertyListEditor`).
> 3. Copy the `Info.plist` file into your application bundle's `Contents` directory.
> 4. Copy the `.icns` file into your application bundle's `Contents/Resources` directory.

Source: [Setting the Application Icon](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/appicon.html#setting-the-application-icon-on-macos)